# The property of the object calls removeAll(), why did it delete itself

Tags: java, arraylist, removeall

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Dto dto = new Dto();

    List<Long> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    aList.add(1L);
    aList.add(2L);
    aList.add(3L);
    dto.setIdList(aList);

    List<Long> bList = new ArrayList<>();
    bList.add(1L);
    bList.add(2L);

    List<Long> tempList = dto.getIdList();
    tempList.removeAll(bList);

    System.out.println(dto.getIdList());

}

@Data
public static class Dto{
    public List<Long> idList;
}
```

This code is a test method I wrote,the code in `System.out.println(dto.getIdList());`,the dto.getIdList() size is 1，and why not 3?why did it delete itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

this is way to solve the problom

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle doc java11#List#removeall](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)), **removeAll()**

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

---

, **So what happens?** the list `idList` has values 1L, 2L, 3L and in `bList`
values 1L, 2L.

When you call `removeAll()` will remove 1L and 2L and remain 3L, then the size is one

Comment: I just want to remove the tempList, but the dto changed same

Comment: Because you received the same list from `get()` method that you put in `set()`

Comment: I didn`t changed dto. IdList anyway ,but dto.getIdList() is 1 also

Comment: If don't the changes reflect in the original list in `Dto` class in `get()` method just call `.clone()` to make a copy of the list